# Exporting Nim Anon Function to C++

Tags: c++, ffi, nim-lang

I am trying to call Nim code from C++. Specifically, a function that takes an anonymous function.

I have the following code in Nim:

```
proc test*(a: proc()) {.exportc.} = a()
```

which I compile to a static library. I then link it to my C++ executable and attempt to define the function with

```
extern "C" test(void a(void);
```

and call it with

```
void anon() { printf("hello"); }
...
test(anon)
```

Everything compiles fine, but when I run the program, it crashes.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

By default, Nim will compile the anonymous proc types as closures represented by a pair of a C function pointer and a void pointer to a structure holding all of the local variables captured by the closure. It will look like this in the generated code:

```
typedef struct {
N_NIMCALL_PTR(void, ClP_0) (void* ClE_0);
void* ClE_0;
} tyProc_XXXXXX;
```

So, to solve the problem you must modify the extern "C" definition of the test function in the C code to accept a compatible structure type. Alternatively, you can ask Nim to compile the proc argument to a regular C function by adding the `cdecl` pragma to the proc type:

```
proc test*(a: proc() {.cdecl.}) {.exportc.} = a()
```

For the full list of calling conventions supported by Nim, check out the section on proc types in the [Nim manual](https://nim-lang.org/docs/manual.html#types-procedural-type).

Comment: Is there any way to assign a `{.cdecl.}` proc to a `{.closure.}` proc? I'm trying to assign the proc in the arguments to a type member proc from the base nim library

Comment: You can use `{.nimcall.}` instead of `cdecl` to achieve the same effect and preserve compatibility with regular Nim procs. Alternatively, you can always wrap any Nim proc in a simple forwarding proc with a different calling convention.